# javascriptのforEach文

Tags: javascript

#### 実現したい内容

ショップのIDを配列に組み込み、実行したときに文字列で「\A/shop/${shopId※配列0}/$ | \A/shop/${shopId※配列1}/$ | \A/shop/${shopId※配列0}/$.... 」を表示させたい。

```
const shopId = [263, 966, 5439, 5478, 5613, 5368, 169, 209, 1499, 42382, 4807, 4808, 5244];

salonId.forEach((salonId) => {
  console.log(`\\A/shop/${shopId}/$`);
});
```

上記のようにEachで実行した後、配列1番目からの文字列の前に「|」(パイプ)でつなげたいのですが、やり方がわからないです。
誰かご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 4):

`forEach` でやりたい場合は、`forEach` の中の処理の結果を格納する別の配列が必要になります。そもそもこういう処理は `map()` のほうが適切でしょう。

```js
shopId.map(s => `\\A/shop/${s}/$`).join('|');
```

Comment: すみません！ありがとうございます。